# How to get the value of variable within the blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c-blocks

Is there anyway to check the value of 'type' variable with completionHandler.

```
-(void)sendApiMethod:(NSString*)apiName ApiType:(NSString*)type
{
 [SendAPI setAPIWithName:@"APIName" completionHandler:^(NSArray *errors) {
        if([type isEqualToString:@"Login"])
        {
           /// Call Some Other function
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Yes; that code will work.  The block will take a copy of `type` when it's created.

Comment: @Droppy when I try to get the value of type variable its shows me 'nil'.

Comment: And it's non-`nil` before the block executes?

Comment: @Droppy Yes, within completionHandler its value is nil.

Comment: I don't understand why that would be.

Comment: Try creating a copy of that string before using it inside the block with this:
__block NSString *typeCopy = type;

Comment: @Bienemann `__block` is only used if you want to write to the variable from within the block, not read it.  Also your code does not copy the object at all.

Comment: Add an NSLog statement before the setAPIWithName, and another one directly inside the block, and show the output of those two NSLog statements.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small piece of code to verify if works (only reading your question I would say yes as Droppy)

I added all there code in a ViewController in a Simple View App.
some assumption:
- all code there for sake of semplicity ....
- I have added a singleton as it seems You are calling a class method.
- instance method is a bit rough, it simply saves name and block
- I added a typedef for blocks to better reading it.

```
#import "ViewController.h"



typedef void (^CompletionBlock)(NSArray *errors);


@interface SendAPI : NSObject

-(void)setAPIWithName:(NSString*)name completionHandler: (CompletionBlock)completionHandler;
+(void)setAPIWithName:(NSString*)name completionHandler: (CompletionBlock)completionHandler;
+(SendAPI*)sharedInstance;

@property (strong) CompletionBlock completionBlock;
@property (strong) NSString * name;

@end


@implementation SendAPI : NSObject

static SendAPI * _singleton = nil;



+(SendAPI*)sharedInstance
{
    if (_singleton == nil)
    {
        _singleton = [[SendAPI alloc] init];
    }
    return _singleton;
}


-(void)setAPIWithName:(NSString*)name completionHandler: (CompletionBlock)completionHandler;
{
    self.completionBlock = completionHandler;
    self.name = [name copy];

    __weak SendAPI * weakRef = self;


    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(4 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSError* err = [NSError errorWithDomain: @"delayed"
                                           code:1111
                                       userInfo: @{@"info": self.name}
                        ];

        weakRef.completionBlock(@[err]);

    });

}


+(void)setAPIWithName:(NSString*)name completionHandler: (CompletionBlock)completionHandler;
{
    [[SendAPI sharedInstance]setAPIWithName:name completionHandler:completionHandler];

}


@end





@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self sendApiMethod:@"HELLO" ApiType: @"Login"];
}




-(void)sendApiMethod:(NSString*)apiName ApiType:(NSString*)type{

    [SendAPI setAPIWithName:@"APIName" completionHandler:^(NSArray *errors) {
     if([type isEqualToString:@"Login"])
     {
         /// Call Some Other function
         NSLog(@"%@", errors);
     }
 }];
}
```

it does LOG correctly